# Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable multiple installation on windows 10

Tags: visual-c++, windows-10

Noticed that many installation of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable on Windows 10. Is it ok to uninstall all of them, and install latest downloaded from Microsoft site ?

I am facing a  library loading issue, and to resolve that trying to organize redistributable installation.

[image]

Comment: You'll notice they are all different versions, so the answer is no.

Comment: No. Those are different versions.

Comment: ok got it, thanks for quick response. But how about version with same title. Like there are 2 installation of 2013, and same for 2015. Do they also require to be kept as it ? If possible please let me have list of version that must be installed. Probably some version has been uninstalled and causing the loading issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received answer as above in comment ( Retired Ninja and Ken White ) that different version need to be kept.

And [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) is the list of latest supported Visual C++ Redistributables from Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

Different version and different platforms. Usually, you must maintain all of them